# How to catch and print an exception of unkown type

Tags: c++, exception

I have some program and every time I run it, it throws an exception.

I don't know how to check what exactly it throws, so my question is: is it possible to catch exception and print it?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

If it derives from `std::exception` you can catch by reference:

```
try
{
    // code that could cause exception
}
catch (const std::exception &exc)
{
    // catch anything thrown within try block that derives from std::exception
    std::cerr << exc.what();
}
```

But if the exception is some class that has is not derived from `std::exception`, you will have to know ahead of time it's type (i.e. should you catch `std::string` or `some_library_exception_base`).

You can do a catch all:

```
try
{
}
catch (...)
{
}
```

but then you can't do anything with the exception.

Comment: @R Samuel Klatchko: thanks a lot, one more question, can I using your method check exceptions of new and delete?

Comment: @helloWorld - yes, this will catch exceptions thrown from `new`, `delete` and any constructor or destructor called by them (provided the `new` or `delete` statement is within the `try` block).

Comment: how should I troubleshoot my problem if exception is not derived from std::exception ?

Comment: @javapowered Did you by chance see Gregory81's answer below (added after your comment)?

Answer (score 24):

In C++11 you have: [std::current_exception](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception)

Example code from site:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>

void handle_eptr(std::exception_ptr eptr) // passing by value is ok
{
    try {
        if (eptr) {
            std::rethrow_exception(eptr);
        }
    } catch(const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "Caught exception \"" << e.what() << "\"\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::exception_ptr eptr;
    try {
        std::string().at(1); // this generates an std::out_of_range
    } catch(...) {
        eptr = std::current_exception(); // capture
    }
    handle_eptr(eptr);
} // destructor for std::out_of_range called here, when the eptr is destructed
```

Comment: This is not helpful, it still handles only std::exception. If something like char* is thrown, this won't help.

Comment: @AIMINPAN just pls don't thow char*... Just why?

Answer (score 6):

If you use ABI for gcc or CLANG you can know the unknown exception type. But it is non standard solution.

See here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24997351/1859469

UPDATE:

The gist of the solution is  (don't use this, the output is mangled)

```
catch(...)
{
   cout << __cxxabiv1::__cxa_current_exception_type()->name();
}
```

For example if you do `throw "foo";` it will return the mangled name `"PKc"`, and if you follow the link for the magic to unmangle, that becomes `"char const*"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try as suggested by R Samuel Klatchko first. If that doesn't help, there's something else that might help:

a) Place a breakpoint on the exception type (handled or unhandled) if your debugger supports it.

b) On some systems, the compiler generates a call to an (undocumented?) function when a throw statement is executed. to find out, what function that is for your system, write a simple hello world program, that throws and catches an exception. start a debugger and place a breakpoint in the exceptions constructor, and see from where it is being called. the caling function is probably something like __throw(). afterwards, start the debugger again with the program you want to investigate as debuggee. place breakpoint on the function mentioned above (__throw or whatever) and run the program. when the exception is thrown, the debugger stops and you are right there to find out why.

Answer (score -1):

Inspired by Dawid Drozd answer:

```
#include <exception>
try
{
    // The code that could throw
}
catch(...)
{
    auto expPtr = std::current_exception();

    try
    {
        if(expPtr) std::rethrow_exception(expPtr);
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e) //it would not work if you pass by value
    {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
}
```

Comment: Still only handles `std::exception`.

Answer (score -1):

Inspired by hamaney answer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>

int main()
{
   try
   { 
      // Your code
   }
   catch (...)
   {
      try
      {
         std::exception_ptr curr_excp;
         if (curr_excp = std::current_exception())
         {
            std::rethrow_exception(curr_excp);
         }
      }
      catch (const std::exception& e)
      {
         std::cout << e.what();
      }
   }
}
```