# C++ - finding the type of a caught default exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, exception

Say I have:

```
try
{
 externalLibrary::doSomething();
}
catch (std::exception &e)
{
 //yay I know what to do
}
catch (...)
{
 //darn, I've no idea what happened!
}
```

There might be cases you get an exception and you don't know where it's coming from or why - in some external library with no debug info. Is there a way to find what was thrown, or otherwise obtain any data associated with it? They *might* be doing:

```
throw myStupidCustomString("here is some really useful information");
```

But I'd never know if I catch `...`

Working in MSVC++ 2008 if it matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because C++ is statically typed, you must catch a known type.  However, you can call an external function (or set of functions) which handle exception types unknown at the point you call them.  If these handlers all have known types, you can register them to be dynamically tried.

```
struct myStupidCustomString {
  myStupidCustomString(char const *what) : what (what) {}
  char const *what;
};

void throws() {
  throw myStupidCustomString("here is some really useful information");
}

// The external library can provide a function, or you can provide a wrapper, which
// extracts information from "unknown" exception types.
std::string extract_from_unknown_external_exception() {
  try { throw; }
  catch (myStupidCustomString &e) {
    return e.what;
  }
  catch (...) {
    throw;  // Rethrow original exception.
  }
}
```

[Use](http://codepad.org/0pIlEz6X):

```
void example() {
  try { throws(); }
  catch (...) {
    try {
      std::string extracted = extract_from_unknown_external_exception();
      std::cout << "extracted: " << extracted << '\n';
    }
    catch (...) {
      // Chain handlers for other types; e.g. exception types from other libraries.
      // Or do something generic for the unknown exception.

      // Or rethrow the original unknown exception:
      throw;
    }
  }
}
```

[Handler chain](http://codepad.org/t2ZsN2li):

```
typedef std::string Extract();
std::vector<Extract*> chain (1, &extract_from_unknown_external_exception);
// Chain would normally be initialized using whatever scheme you prefer for
// initializing global objects.
// A list or other container (including a manual linked list that doesn't
// require dynamic allocation) may be more appropriate, depending on how you
// want to register and unregister handlers.
std::string process_chain() {
  for (std::vector<Extract*>::iterator x = chain.begin(); x != chain.end(); ++x) {
    try {
      return (*x)();
    }
    catch (...) {}  // That handler couldn't handle it.  Proceed to next.
  }
  throw;  // None could handle it, rethrow original exception.
}

void example() {
  try { throws(); }
  catch (...) {
    try {
      std::string extracted = process_chain();
      std::cout << "extracted: " << extracted << '\n';
    }
    catch (...) {
      throw;  // Rethrow unknown exception, or otherwise handle it.
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, if you know implementation specifics, you can use those to extract whatever additional information your implementation exposes.  C++0x exposes some specifics in a portable way, too; look at std::exception_ptr.

Comment: Hi, I think this is a great answer. However, I can't find any information in the standard about whether or not this is standard behavior. I have tested it, and it works both in VisualStudio, GCC, and LLVM, but I'm not entirely sure why. So entering a new `try{}catch(){}` block doesn't affect the current exception in any way? Thanks!

Comment: I suppose I'm also not sure why it wouldn't work.. It seems to make sense to me that entering into a try block wouldn't affect any current exceptions, but I guess I just want to double check.

Answer (score 19):

If you use gcc or CLANG you can use a trick to know the 'unknown' exception type. Keep in mind that this is NON-standard !

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cxxabi.h>


using namespace __cxxabiv1;

std::string util_demangle(std::string to_demangle)
{
    int status = 0;
    char * buff = __cxxabiv1::__cxa_demangle(to_demangle.c_str(), NULL, NULL, &status);
    std::string demangled = buff;
    std::free(buff);
    return demangled;
}

struct MyCustomClass
{};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    try
    {
        throw MyCustomClass();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "\nUnknown exception type: '" << util_demangle(__cxa_current_exception_type()->name()) << "'" << std::endl;
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to know the type of the exception in C++ (in `catch(...)` block, I mean, of cource)

You could just hope that you know what exactly `externalLibrary::doSomething();` does, if you have written it, or, as in your case, you could just hope, that there's really nice documentation for `externalLibrary::doSomething();` and read it, if there's such. All good libraries have detailed documentation.

Comment: Detailed documentation of exceptions isn't as common as decent documentation of params, in my experience. But if that's how it is, I'll just have to test standard possibilities... what about system exceptions?

Comment: What do you mean by "what about system exceptions?" I don't know if they can be caught in a C++ program :? Also, most of the libraries, I've used, have their own exception hierarchy that is well documented. But, of course, this doesn't mean, that all libraries have such thing. Also, if it's C lib, you know, that no exceptions are thrown.

Comment: I meant, aren't there special ways to catch things like null-ptr access, div/0 and so on? I thought there were ways to do catch such problems where the 3rd-party lib is buggy?

Comment: I really don't know. It would be really nice if there's such way :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't in standard C++.  I would consider such exceptions to be very exceptional, and handle them by trying to log the fact that you had a bad exception, and then try to quit the program, while you still can.

If you're lucky, you may be able to save any data.