# about c++ try -catch

Tags: c++, exception

I read code in a large project, that includs a lot of code like:

```
try
{
}
catch(...)
{
}
```

Literally, in the parenthesis after "catch", there is "..." in it. Not something like "exception e".

This makes me a little worry. 
Is this practice good or safe?
thanks.

Comment: I'd imagine this to be a wildcard of sorts?  Can someone else confirm that?

Comment: @MGZero, yes it's a wildcard, it catches *everything*.

Comment: Duplicate of [c++ try catch practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967062/c-try-catch-practices)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, this is a terrible practice.

If you `catch(...)`, you have no idea what you've caught.  It catches all C++ exceptions (and on some platforms with some settings, it catches other exceptions too, like structured exceptions in Visual C++).

If you have no idea what exception was thrown, you have no idea what the state of the system is:  how do you know whether it is safe for the program to continue running?

The only two ways that it is absolutely safe to exit a `catch(...)` block is to terminate the program or to rethrow the exception (using `throw;`).  The latter is occasionally useful if you need to perform some cleanup when an exception is thrown but can't rely on a destructor.

Comment: It can be reasonable if you have some cleanup you need to do, and use `throw;` to re-throw when done. Of course, using an RAII class would be even better.

Comment: @bdonlan:  You're absolutely right, and I suppose it could be useful to use a `catch (...)` in some circumstances when you are writing an RAII container yourself (I don't recall ever having had to do this, but I suppose it's possible).

Comment: Exceptions thrown from destructors during stack unwinding abort the program; in a RAII container it would indeed be useful to explicitly abort the program when an exception occurs in the destructor to ensure the abort happens even if you're _not_ doing stack unwinding

Answer (score 3):

`catch(...)` catches *all* exceptions.

Normally, you would not want to do this. You have no idea what it is you just caught, and if you leave the catch block you have just silently ignored some kind of error. This could lead to very bad things happening later on. Since you have no idea what error just happened, you have no way to recover from it, and thus the only reasonable thing to do is to either allow the exception to continue (re-throw it) or abort the program's execution (call `abort()` or `exit()`).

However, if you have some cleanup you need to perform, it may be reasonable to catch all exceptions, perform the cleanup, then *re-throw* the exception:

```
try {
  // ...
} catch (...) {
  abortTransaction();
  throw;
}
```

That said, it's usually better to use so-called [RAII classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) to automate this cleanup:

```
DBTransaction txn = db.StartTransaction();

// do stuff that may throw; if it throws, txn will be destroyed,
// and its destructor can abort the transaction
// As such, an explicit try { } catch(...) { } isn't needed
```

Answer (score 1):

It catches all exceptions. See this code:

```
try {
   throw CSomeOtherException();
}
catch(...) {  // Handle all exceptions
   // Respond (perhaps only partially) to exception
   throw;       // Pass exception to some other handler
}
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dekhbbc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> You do not need to declare this parameter; in many cases it may be
>   sufficient to notify the handler that a particular type of exception
>   has occurred. However, if you do not declare an exception object in
>   the exception-declaration, you will not have access to that object in
>   the catch handler clause.
>
> A throw-expression with no operand re-throws the exception currently
>   being handled. Such an expression should appear only in a catch
>   handler or in a function called from within a catch handler. The
>   re-thrown exception object is the original exception object (not a
>   copy). For example:

Hope this helps!

This practice is safe only if you have proper handlers written for exceptions. Avoiding it is better in my opinion.